# View permission / owner of full directory tree

Tags: command-line, files, ls

I remember doing someting like "XXX /home/user/dir/child/file" and it returned the owner and/or permission of:

```
/home
/home/user
/home/user/dir
/home/user/child
/home/user/child/file
```

But I don't remember what this command was. Anybody any idea?

Comment: Not seeing anything enlightening from `apropos mode` or `apropos permissions` on OS X and Debian. Do you know what platform/distribution you were using? Could it have been a site-local command? You could script such a tool using `dirname` and `stat`.

Comment: Using Arch Linux, and a pretty vanilla installation so not too many extra tools installed. Note that it was owners AND/OR permissions, I'm not sure at this point. Either would be useful.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The command could have been:

```
namei -m /home/user/dir/child/file
```

Comment: `namei -mo` is great, that it also gives you the owner.

Comment: BEWARE: namei won't show linux ACL's or SELinux MAC's. I figured out that an ACL was blocking nginx by manually checking with `sudo su nginx -s/bin/bash`

Answer (score 57):

I think you might be thinking of the `tree` command. For example:

```
$ tree -pufid apps/glassfish3/ | less
apps/glassfish3
[drwxr-xr-x saml    ]  apps/glassfish3/bin
[drwxr-xr-x saml    ]  apps/glassfish3/glassfish
[drwxr-xr-x saml    ]  apps/glassfish3/glassfish/bin
[drwxr-xr-x saml    ]  apps/glassfish3/glassfish/config
[drwxr-xr-x saml    ]  apps/glassfish3/glassfish/docs
[drwxr-xr-x saml    ]  apps/glassfish3/glassfish/docs/api
[drwxr-xr-x saml    ]  apps/glassfish3/glassfish/docs/api/doc-files
[drwxr-xr-x saml    ]  apps/glassfish3/glassfish/docs/api/javax
[drwxr-xr-x saml    ]  apps/glassfish3/glassfish/docs/api/javax/annotation
[drwxr-xr-x saml    ]  apps/glassfish3/glassfish/docs/api/javax/annotation/security
[drwxr-xr-x saml    ]  apps/glassfish3/glassfish/docs/api/javax/annotation/sql
[drwxr-xr-x saml    ]  apps/glassfish3/glassfish/docs/api/javax/decorator
[drwxr-xr-x saml    ]  apps/glassfish3/glassfish/docs/api/javax/ejb
[drwxr-xr-x saml    ]  apps/glassfish3/glassfish/docs/api/javax/ejb/embeddable
...
...
```

The above switches do the following:

- `-p` - permissions
- `-u` - username/userid
- `-f` - full path
- `-i` - don't print indentation lines
- `-d` - print directories only

#### References

- [tree man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree)

Comment: I think it was asked to display the ancestors of `/home/user/dir/child/file` not the children.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens - yes I realize that but there isn't a command that I'm aware of that does exactly that, there is however the tree command that does what I showed and it's suspiciously similar to what the OP was thinking of.

Comment: Is the `-u` really necessary? It seems it's default here (Tree ver. 1.6.0 under GNU bash 4.2.45). Is there an option to silence the "username/userid"?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris - if I drop that switch I do not get the username. My ver: tree v1.6.0. I'm on Fedora 19, GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
.

Comment: Different "defaults" between the bash versions? Thanks for informing.

Answer (score 3):

After giving it some thougth I came up with this

```
#!/bin/sh
l_path=$1
while [ "$l_path" != / -a "$l_path" != . ]; do
     ls -ld $l_path
     l_path=$(dirname -- "$l_path")
done
```

The output looks like this

```
-rw------- 1 tant tant 181016423 Jun 25 23:49:17 2013 /home/tant/test_file
drwxr-xr-x 85 tant tant 5632 Jul  9 19:40:11 2013 /home/tant
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 8 Sep  4 23:53:27 2012 /home -> usr/home
```

I hope it is ok that it is in reverse order.

Based on the comments, here's a way to list from the root downwards:

```
#!/bin/sh
l_path=$1
while [ "$l_path" != / -a "$l_path" != . ]; do
     ls -ld $l_path
     l_path=$(dirname -- "$l_path")
done | sed '1!G;h;$!d'
```

Comment: You can reverse with `| tac` if you have it, or `| sed '1!G;h;$!d'` if not.

Comment: This will break for relative paths. Do `[ "$l_path" != / -a "$l_path" != . ]` instead.

Comment: @Evan Teitelman dirname should gives the full path

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens no, it'll return a dot for relative path in the end.

Comment: Also, `stat -l` should probably be `stat` or `ls -ld`.

Comment: One a side note, to get an absolute path for a file or directory, you can use `realpath`.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman `realpath` often is not installed in the system

Comment: ah ok `stat -l` is BSD specific thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In the directory of which you want to know the ancester's permissions and owners:

```
for i in $(seq 0 $(pwd | tr -cd / | wc -c)) ; do pwd ; ls -lad ; cd .. ; done
```

Note that after that, you'll be in `/` :) if you want to go back to where you were, wrap the command inside

```
HERE=$(pwd)
...
cd ${HERE}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### List permissions of every directory in a directory path (up or down)

```
alias dirls='_dirls() { path="$(realpath $1)";_path="";for i in " " ${path//\// }; do _path="$_path$i/"; ls -ld $_path; done; unset _path; };_dirls'

alias dirls2='_dirls2() { path="$(realpath $1)"; while [[ "$path" != "/" ]]; do ls -ld "$path"; path="$(dirname "$path")"; done; ls -ldh /; };_dirls2'
```

---

```
eg:

# dirls /usr/local/bin
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root root 236 Nov 11 19:01 /
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root root 181 Dec  7 11:50 /usr/
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root root 205 Nov 22 14:06 /usr/local/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Dec  5 12:19 /usr/local/bin/

# dirls2 /usr/local/bin
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Dec  5 12:19 /usr/local/bin
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root root 205 Nov 22 14:06 /usr/local
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root root 181 Dec  7 11:50 /usr
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root root 236 Nov 11 19:01 /
```

Answer (score -1):

The command you are looking for listing permissions and owners/groups is **ls -l**.

-l option is used for long listing format.

> ls -l /path/to/list

In addition, if you want to list and the **hidden files** then add the **-a(all)** option.

> ls -al /path/to/list

Also, if you want to list permissions in your **subdirectories** use **-R (recursive)** option.

> ls -Rl /path/to/list

The first column displays the permissions(read(r), write(w), execute(x)) and some special permissions(directories(d), -(regular file)) and the 3rd and 4th column shows you the file/directory owner and group respectively.

Comment: I don't think that's what is asked for. Looks like the asker is looking for a list of permissions of directories that lead to a file.